# Inserting placeholders and radio button in SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have an problem I can't seem to solve.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active,owner_service) VALUES ( )';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param( );
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':active' => $activasion,
            '"$owner_service"' => $POST_['owner_service']
        ));
```

'username, password, email and active' are all placeholders but 'owner_service' is a radio button and I don't know how to write it in code if I want to insert it into my table. Do I use ' :xx ' for the placeholders and ' ? ' for my radio button? So the code will look like

```
(:username, :password, :email, :active, ?)
```

and in the bind_param write

```
('$owner_service') ?
```

Comment: I don't understand why the name of your radio button parameter would be variable..

Comment: P.S.  There is no bind_param in PDO, it is bindParam.  bind_param is mysqli.  You're mixing up your APIs.

Comment: I know they can, I mixed up my response too. That's what I get for rushing through something @Devon ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `'"$owner_service"' => $POST_['owner_service']` looks all weird. I think it should be `$_POST['owner_service']` and as @Devon said, why is the column name variable?